# Web-serving a file : Firefox truncates name

Tags: firefox, mime-types, lighttpd

I'm serving a file from Lighttpd whose name contains space-characters. I'm using mimetype "application/octet-stream"

When I download this in Chrome, it works perfectly. But when I download in Firefox, the filename is truncated at the first space.

Is this to do with the mimetype? With some other lightty config? Or maybe something to do with the kind of space-character I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to urlencode your links. Spaces are easily misunderstood in URLS.

The url code for space is %20 or you can also use +

So for

```
http://example.com/test file.jpg
```

```
You would use:
http://example.com/test%20file.jpg
or
http://example.com/test+file.jpg
```

I prefer to not use filenames with spaces in them.